# Can a non-resident claim an out of pocket health cost tax deduction?

Tags: united-states, taxes, insurance

I am a graduate student and my health insurance is paid by the university. I had an emergency visit and few subsequent doctor's visit in last financial year which were not covered by the insurance and I paid for them. Can I claim this for tax deductions? I am here on F1 visa from India.

Answer (score 1):

Non-residents cannot deduct medical expenses.

But as an Indian, because of the US-India tax treaty, you can take a standard deduction. I'm not sure if you can claim medical expenses deduction under the treaty when itemizing (check with a professional who's specializing on US-India tax treaty).

Comment: Emergency visit and subsequent drs visits... OP might have meant non-resident alien.